# Style a dynamically created div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dynamic

I would like to apply a css style to a  element after it's created. The element is created by a plugin, so I can't access the event in which it is created.

This element has the .appointments-address-field class. I have tried to add a simple style:

```
.appointments-address-field {
    background: #fff;
}
```

... with no success. Then I tried to attach a delegated load event in jQuery:

```
$(document).on('load', '.appointments-address-field'), function() {
    $('.appointments-address-field').css('background', '#fff');
});
```

... with no success either.

How can I apply a style to that element?

Edit: Sorry, I misspelled my jQuery code. Many of you have suggested to use .css instead of .style, but I did use that.

Comment: You were correct in the first place, but your css selector must be at least as specific as any existing background style. Use a tool like Chrome's F12 DOM inspector to view where the styling for an element is coming from.

Comment: what plugin are you using? doesn't the plugin provide a callback or an associated event?

Comment: I am using the Appointments+ plugin for wordpress. Sadly, I can't access easily any of it's events.

Comment: @Trisztán Thar: Are you able to post full page HTML or a link to the site? As detailed below `!important` is a worst-case solution for *when nothing else works* and is probably not appropriate in this case (unless the existing style uses `!important` already, which I doubt). Thanks.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie sure: escapezone.hu/foglalas/ first, you have to select a date, then an hour and after this, the form that appears is where the element is

Comment: By default that address row you are trying to highlight is hidden. My Hungarian is not great, so how do you make that address line appear?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it. The main goal isn't to change it's background color, but to hide it with display:none, then insert a value into it's child input field. I used a pseudo code, because it didn't need explanation and I had problems with the css styling. Actually, you can change the language to english via the language switcher on the bottom of the page. Edit: the translation isn't updated yet, so you'll have to stick with the hungarian version for now.

Comment: Ah. I'm used to language selection at the page top :) If the aim is to completely different to the question asked, it's no wonder the answers didn't match your requirements. This is a classic "XY" question: where what you asked for is completely different to the real question. If all issues are not sorted, suggest you add a new question with the real aims :)

Comment: Actually, it isn't a different aim. The aim is to add a css style to an element, it really doesn't matter if that style is a background color or a display:none. The value thing is not a problem, I just added is as plus information, so you know why I want to hide the element.

Comment: Wouldn't you say "but to hide it with display:none, *then insert a value into it's child input field*" is outside the scope of the original question which is about styling only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
.appointments-address-field {
    background: #fff !important;
}
```

problems can be another style directive put different background

Comment: @Trisztán Thar: `!important` is a last-case fix as it causes subsequent override issues and is best avoided. http://james.padolsey.com/usability/dont-use-important/ You should first try and find the original selector in the CSS. Using say Chrome as suggested.

Comment: me too i think that the best solution is a more specific definition in the css like say @trueblueaussie; but now we are sure that problem is in css :-)

Comment: @Alessandro Marchisio: if you follow the comments, you will find this was an XY problem and your `!important` fix was actually applied to `display: none` instead... Who knew :)

Answer (score 4):

You were correct in the first place to use CSS and not code, but your css selector must be at least as *specific* as any existing background style applied to that element. I am of course assuming your styling is already included *after* the plugin's styling.

Use a tool like Chrome's F12 DOM inspector to view where the styling for an element is coming from and whether that is more specific.

e.g. it may need to be something like:

```
.some-parent-wrapper .some-appointment .some-group .appointments-address-field {
    background: #fff;
}
```

If you were able to provide a link to the actual site, it would be easy to suggest the correct selector.

**Update:**

Do not resort to the easy fallback of `!important` *unless the current selector also uses it*: http://james.padolsey.com/usability/dont-use-important/

Answer (score 3):

Your first way should work, provided:

1. You include it in a stylesheet **after** the stylesheet related to the plugin (if any).
2. The plugin's stylesheet doesn't use `!important`; if it does, you can add that to your style.
3. The plugin doesn't style the background of the element directly; if it does, you can use `!important` in your stylesheet to win.
4. The plugin's rule isn't *more specific* than yours; if it is, make your rule more specific. In any modern browser, you can right-click the element, open the dev tools, and see the rules applied to it.

Fighting style wars with `!important` isn't ideal. If the plugin is making this difficult in that way, you may be better off finding out what event (if any) is fired when the plugin adds the element, and then running your

```
$('.appointments-address-field').css('background', '#fff');
```

...code in response to that. (`load` is **not** fired when elements are added to the DOM, which is why that didn't work.) Also note that the function is `css`, not `style`.

Answer (score 1):

Please use .css of jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.appointments-address-field').css({'background':'#fff','border':"#000"});
});
```

after loading plugin, this line added in your code if u have ready event already included please below code only

```
$('.appointments-address-field').css({'background':'#fff','border':"#000"});
```

Comment: It is likely the class is added by the plugin, in which case a pure CSS solution is preferable.

Comment: Who keeps upvoting this invalid code? Since when do divs have a delegated `ready` event???